# Where are User Patches stored for GarageBand?

Tags: garageband

I have created some nice guitar patches (combination of amp, effects, etc.) and I want to save them so I can reuse them in other songs.

I click the Save button at the bottom of the Sounds pane and the file browser goes to the folder where I saved my last song. I save the patch there but it doesn't show up in GarageBand in the Sounds pane.

Seems there must be a central location where patches should be saved in order to be available but I'm not finding it. I poked around in ~/Library a bit but did not find the "User Presets" folder. Apple says:

"Custom patches are saved to a User Patches folder in the Library (created in the Library the first time you save a patch). You can use these patches in any GarageBand project."

but this does not seem to be my experience. Should I create a User Patches folder somewhere, and if so where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default location that the patch file browser for audio patches will start in is

```
~/Music/Audio Music Apps/Patches/Audio
```

Patches in this folder show for me in the library under ‘User Patches’.

Comment: Yay - that's it! Thank you. Such a simple question but so hard to find the answer.